# Way to change already printed string

Tags: python, string

Yesterday I coded a Hangman game. I got it finished and it works but now im asking myself "could it be better"?
I thought of a line of underscores to let the user know how many digits there are and than a way to chose. If the chosen letter is in the word that needs to be guessed it replaces the underscore with the letter.

[This is my try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9day.png)

I dont know how to change the printed string or refresh the choice option.

Thx for any answer.

Comment: Maybe try using `sys.clear` to remove the printed line and print it again with a small change? Also, remember to always copy paste code rather than posting an image to stay in line with stack overflow regulation.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `end='\r'` to the line which should be overwritten.

For the last line you should use the default end switch, otherwise the line is overwritten in the terminal (at least on linux).

```
import time
print('This is line 1', end='\r')
time.sleep(1)
print('This is line 2')
```